# Django syntax error: unexpected token `('

Tags: python, django

I've installed Django and moved django-admin to usr/local/bin as suggested on the setup page. When I run

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

It says django-admin permission denied. Django setup page suggests:

```
sudo chmod +x django-admin
```

This removes the permission error but introduces the following:

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject 
from: can't read /var/mail/django.utils.version
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py: line 3: `VERSION = (3, 0, 8, 'final', 0)'
```

Any idea how to resolve the error? I am using a Mac. Django version 3.0.8. and Python3. Thanks!

Comment: Your shell is trying to execute the script, rather than Python.  Try putting `python ` in front of that command.

Comment: Please try executing as `django-admin startproject myproject` instead of `django-admin.py startproject myproject`. Remove the `.py` from `django-admin`

Comment: Thanks! The error does not show up anymore when I put python3 in front. But now the project directory is nowhere to be found. Even when I tell it where to create the directory, nothing shows up.

Comment: @KashyapKN it says command not found when I use without .py. I am using macOS